# Selecting value from 3 columns based on count with large data set optimization

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of addresses anywhere from 50k to 300k or greater. I have 3 columns that include closest store 1, closest store 2, and closest store 3 for each row of addresses.  The formula i use is giving me the output I want, however, it take hours to calculate and occasionally errors out. I am looking for a better way to analyze the data set. The example data set is below.

```
| Store1 | Store2 | Store3 | CS1   | CS2    | CS3   | Map_store |
|--------|--------|--------|-------|--------|-------|-----------|
| 1111   | 2222   | 3333   | 0     | 0      | 0     | 1111      |
| 1111   | 2222   | 4444   | 1     | 0      | 0     | 2222      |
| 2222   | 5555   | 6666   | 1     | 1      | 0     | 6666      |
| 3333   | 7777   | 8888   | 0     | 0      | 0     | 3333      |
```

There is more columns referring to the address data but this is the core of the data set.  Store 1, 2, and 3 are aligned from closest to the address. This is why i default to store1.

The formula in "CS1" is...

```
=Countif($G$1:G1,"="&[@[Store1]])
```

The same formula is for CS2 and CS3 but with [@[Store2]] and [@[Store3]]

The Map_Store formula is...

```
=index(Table1[@Store1]:[Store3],1,MATCH(MIN(Table1[@[CS1]:[CS3]),Table1[@[CS1]:[CS3],0)*2-1)
```

This chooses the minimum value of the count columns to make sure the stores are evenly distributed. The output is correct, just process intensive.

I am hoping to optimize this process because it take anywhere from 3 to 6 hours for a list of 80k to 200k addresses to map.  Any direction of assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Countif is notoriusly slow on big data sets. Try to optimaze that part some exaples here: https://superuser.com/questions/748509/excel-countif-slow

Comment: Btw. Why use `=Countif($G$1:G1,"="&[@[Store1]])` instead of `=Countif($G$1:G1,[@Store1])` - probably does not change much however is cleaner.

Comment: Is the G column your Map_Store column? If so, how are these formulas not circularly dependant?

Comment: The G column is, The count begins on the header row, row 1. The formula is always looking to the above selection.  I'm open to a new formula idea, or VBA options. I wanted to share what is working for me now. Its just very time consuming and process intensive.

Comment: Your index formula is broken (missing some square brackets) and I'm unable to reproduce your top table using any corrected versions I can think of (D4 and E4, in particular, aren't matching.